# Beginner Blogger: Anchoring header to very top of website

Tags: html, blogger

I'm new to Blogger, and HTML and am trying to set up a fashion-blogging website on Blogger.

I've been successful in making the header image static (that is, doesn't move when scrolling through posts), but unfortunately it isn't aligned at the very top of the website. This makes it look very odd as content disappears as it scrolls under the header image, and reappears briefly as it scrolls between the header image and top of page.

I've looked into some basic HTML, but there is a huge jump from basic HTML to the HTML I see when I try to edit HTML directly on my Blogger website. I just want the header image to be aligned at the very top.

Can anyone help? Anything is appreciated.

Comment: Try adding this: `margin-left:-80px;` to your image disposed in your header.

Comment: Looks stuck to the top here.

Comment: You should always post your code here, and for just this reason. When I visited your site you had already remedied the problem. So I (and future visitors to this question) aren't be able to see the original state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the css `top:0` to the DIV with ID "header-outer"

**Plus**

Why do you have so much unnecessary markup? You could replace all of this:

```
<div class="header-outer">
<div class="header-cap-top cap-top">
<div class="cap-left"></div>
<div class="cap-right"></div>
</div>
<div class="fauxborder-left header-fauxborder-left">
<div class="fauxborder-right header-fauxborder-right"></div>
<div class="region-inner header-inner">
<div id="header" class="header section"><div id="Header1" class="widget Header">
    <div id="header-inner">
        <a style="display: block" href="http://monsemble.blogspot.ca/">
            <img width="833px; " height="216px; " style="display: block" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-91QDCMg_EsU/UcsYVdMvLQI/AAAAAAAAACw/Oa727KfuuBk/s1600/header.jpg" id="Header1_headerimg" alt="MONSEMBLE">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="header-cap-bottom cap-bottom">
    <div class="cap-left"></div>
    <div class="cap-right"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

With:

```
<div class="header-outer">
    <a style="display: block" href="http://monsemble.blogspot.ca/">
        <img width="833px; " height="216px; " style="display: block" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-91QDCMg_EsU/UcsYVdMvLQI/AAAAAAAAACw/Oa727KfuuBk/s1600/header.jpg" id="Header1_headerimg" alt="MONSEMBLE">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced something similar on my Blogger blog and I noticed that inspite of me switching off the navbar that comes with the Blogger website, in the the HTML code there was still a division on the top of the page for the navbar. I removed it from the template and was able to move the header image to the top of the webpage.

I removed this section of the code -

```
<b:section class='navbar' id='navbar' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='no'>
    <b:widget id='Navbar1' locked='true' title='Navbar' type='Navbar'>
    <b:includable id='main'>&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
    function setAttributeOnload(object, attribute, val) {
    if(window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener(&#39;load&#39;,
        function(){ object[attribute] = val; }, false);
    } else {
        window.attachEvent(&#39;onload&#39;, function(){ object[attribute] = val; });
    }
    }
&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;div id=&quot;navbar-iframe-container&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
        gapi.load(&quot;gapi.iframes:gapi.iframes.style.bubble&quot;, function() {
        if (gapi.iframes &amp;&amp; gapi.iframes.getContext) {
            gapi.iframes.getContext().openChild({
                url: &#39;https://www.blogger.com/navbar.g?targetBlogID\0752197236978911214706\46blogName\75MahekMody.com\46publishMode\75PUBLISH_MODE_HOSTED\46navbarType\75DISABLED\46layoutType\75LAYOUTS\46searchRoot\75http://www.mahekmody.com/search\46blogLocale\75en\46v\0752\46homepageUrl\75http://www.mahekmody.com/\46vt\0753008633957882384298&#39;,
                where: document.getElementById(&quot;navbar-iframe-container&quot;),
                id: &quot;navbar-iframe&quot;
            });
        }
        });
    &lt;/script&gt;&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
(function() {
var script = document.createElement(&#39;script&#39;);
script.type = &#39;text/javascript&#39;;
script.src = &#39;//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/google_top_exp.js&#39;;
var head = document.getElementsByTagName(&#39;head&#39;)[0];
if (head) {
head.appendChild(script);
}})();
&lt;/script&gt;
</b:includable>
    </b:widget>
</b:section>
```